# tfs, the real location of team project

Tags: tfs, project, location

I have a project on server call "MyApp". I connect the tfs server, retrieve and save project my desktop.

Then change project name "MyApp" to "MyAppTemp" on server..

Call project again from server, i expect a problem but no problem. So I understood that the project also has got a different location on the server.

Where is real location of my team project?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit confusing, because you cannot locally save a team project.

A team project is a set of settings and options, which you can only see from the connected server, but not 'download' in any way. Maybe you're confusing this with Visual Studio projects, which is something totally different?

Anyway, data for a team project live in the TFS database.

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

A workspace in TFS contains the mappings between a location in TFS Source Control and your local file system. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181383(v=VS.100).aspx